# Test only the currently active backend with Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm trying to test our web application with the E2E Testing Framework Cypress. But now I've ran into a problem.

For our webapp we are using two backends one is active and the other inactive. But when testing it is not known which backend is currently active. How can I now write a test that doesnt fail just because one of the URL's cant be reached. Here is the code I currently have.

```
describe("Backend Test", () => {
  it("Test Backend 1", () => {
    cy.visit("BACKEND1_HOSTNAME.company.com") //Lets say this fails because backend 1 is currently  inactive
  })

  it("Test Backend 2", () => {
    cy.visit("BACKEND2_HOSTNAME.company.com") //This will work because its active
  })
})
```

In this scenario the whole test-suite will fail because one of the backends doesnt respond because its not active.

Is there any way I can avoid the test from failing as long as **one** of the tests is succesful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run one of the backend in a `cy.request()` to find out which is active.

```js
describe("Backend Test", () => {

  let activeUrl;

  before(() => {
    cy.request('BACKEND1_HOSTNAME.company.com', {failOnStatusCode:false})
      .then(response => {
        activeUrl = (repsonse.statusCode === 200) ? 'BACKEND1_HOSTNAME.company.com'
          : 'BACKEND2_HOSTNAME.company.com'
      })
  })

  it("Test active backend", () => {
    cy.visit(activeUrl)
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for that recommendation I will try it on monday. I didn't use requests until now so I didnt know this was possible!

Comment: On our productive I now have another problem. Even with `failOnStatusCode: false` Cypress fails with the following message: `cy.request() failed trying to load:

https://OURCOMPANYURL/

We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request failed without a response.

We received this error at the network level:

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND` any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It looks like `failOnStatusCode: false` will only catch errors in the response, but if one backend is turned off, it's probably causing the `ENOTFOUND` error.

Comment: I for now use a nasty workaround with `Cypress.on("fail", ...)`